# Unresolved reference: kept in compose project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, build.gradle, dagger-hilt

I am building jetpack compose project in android studio
and i am unable to add Dagger Hilt libraries.  it gives error of 'unable to resolve "kept"'

I have added classpath and plugin for Dagger-Hilt, and i have added the dependecies like below

```
implementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
kept ("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.43.2")
implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0")
```

Comment: You are having typo mistake it's not ```kept``` it's ```kapt```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `kept` in Android. Please change the spelling from `kept` to **`kapt`**.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35564721)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine: This is an answer. The issue is that the question was caused by a typo, so the question should be closed.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Reasonable point.